# Why does `cd /../` not return an error in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cd

In bash (or, I'm assuming, any linux shell), I would expect `cd /../` to return an error. I interpret that to be asking for the parent of the root of the directory tree. Since it's the root of the directory tree, I was under the impression that it has no parent.

However, it returns no error, and looks to be equivalent to `cd /`. I would also expect an error from `cd / && cd ../` for the same reason: asking for the parent of the root directory, but it has the same result.

Why is this?